# R: mixedsort on multiple vectors (columns)

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, natural-sort

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033510/order-data-frame-by-multiple-columns-naturally), which was marked as [a duplicate to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396582/order-a-mixed-vector-numbers-with-letters), but the suggested solution does not work.

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(A=paste(sample(LETTERS, 4), sample(1:20, 20), sep=""),
        B=paste(sample(1:20, 20), sample(LETTERS, 4), sep=""),
        C=sample(LETTERS, 20), D=sample(1:100, 20), value=rnorm(20))

> mydf
     A   B C  D       value
1   G5  6N T  9 -0.68875569
2  J18  8T R 87 -0.70749516
3  N19  1A L 34  0.36458196
4  U12  7K Z 82  0.76853292
5  G11 14N J 98 -0.11234621
6   J1 20T F 32  0.88110773
7   N3 17A B 45  0.39810588
8  U14 19K W 83 -0.61202639
9   G9 15N U 80  0.34111969
10 J20  3T I 36 -1.12936310
11  N8  9A K 70  1.43302370
12 U16 16K G 86  1.98039990
13  G6 10N M 39 -0.36722148
14  J7 18T D 62 -1.04413463
15 N13  5A Y 35  0.56971963
16  U4 11K N 28 -0.13505460
17 G17  4N O 64  2.40161776
18 J15  2T C 17 -0.03924000
19  N2 12A P 59  0.68973936
20 U10 13K X 10  0.02800216
```

I want to order it according to columns `A` to `D`, but `A` and `D` are mixed, so *natural* order is required.

I know I can apply regular ordering, like:

```
mydf2 <- mydf[do.call(order, c(mydf[1:4], list(decreasing = FALSE))),]

> mydf2
     A   B C  D       value
5  G11 14N J 98 -0.11234621
17 G17  4N O 64  2.40161776
1   G5  6N T  9 -0.68875569
13  G6 10N M 39 -0.36722148
9   G9 15N U 80  0.34111969
6   J1 20T F 32  0.88110773
18 J15  2T C 17 -0.03924000
2  J18  8T R 87 -0.70749516
10 J20  3T I 36 -1.12936310
14  J7 18T D 62 -1.04413463
15 N13  5A Y 35  0.56971963
3  N19  1A L 34  0.36458196
19  N2 12A P 59  0.68973936
7   N3 17A B 45  0.39810588
11  N8  9A K 70  1.43302370
20 U10 13K X 10  0.02800216
4  U12  7K Z 82  0.76853292
8  U14 19K W 83 -0.61202639
12 U16 16K G 86  1.98039990
16  U4 11K N 28 -0.13505460
```

But this is not the result I need. I need `10` after `9`, not after `1` (you can check column `A` to see it is not in the order I need.)

In the comments of my original question, it was suggested to use the `multi.mixedorder` function.

However, as you can see below, the result is identical to the one using just `order`, which is still not what I want.

```
multi.mixedorder <- function(..., na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE){
    do.call(order, c(
        lapply(list(...), function(l){
            if(is.character(l)){
                factor(l, levels=mixedsort(unique(l)))
            } else {
                l
            }
        }),
        list(na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
    ))
}

mydf3 <- mydf[do.call(multi.mixedorder, c(mydf[1:4], list(decreasing = FALSE))),]

> mydf3
    A   B C  D       value
5  G11 14N J 98 -0.11234621
17 G17  4N O 64  2.40161776
1   G5  6N T  9 -0.68875569
13  G6 10N M 39 -0.36722148
9   G9 15N U 80  0.34111969
6   J1 20T F 32  0.88110773
18 J15  2T C 17 -0.03924000
2  J18  8T R 87 -0.70749516
10 J20  3T I 36 -1.12936310
14  J7 18T D 62 -1.04413463
15 N13  5A Y 35  0.56971963
3  N19  1A L 34  0.36458196
19  N2 12A P 59  0.68973936
7   N3 17A B 45  0.39810588
11  N8  9A K 70  1.43302370
20 U10 13K X 10  0.02800216
4  U12  7K Z 82  0.76853292
8  U14 19K W 83 -0.61202639
12 U16 16K G 86  1.98039990
16  U4 11K N 28 -0.13505460
```

Answer (score 1):

OK solved it, the `multi.mixedsort` function needs a fix to be able to deal with factors:

```
multi.mixedorder <- function(..., na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE){
    do.call(order, c(
        lapply(list(...), function(l){
            if(is.character(l)){
                factor(l, levels=mixedsort(unique(l)))
            } else {
                factor(as.character(l), levels=mixedsort(levels(l)))
            }
        }),
        list(na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)
    ))
}
```

Otherwise convert all factor columns in `mydf` into character, with:

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.character)
```

but with the fix, this shouldn't be needed